# 7z questions and such

Tags: 7zip

I am wanting to learn the ropes with 7z.  This isn't working...I followed 7z --help:

```
7z x -r beans.7z personal.php
```

I want to make a .7z file called "beans.7z" and what contains the file "personal.php"

The error I get is:

```
Error:
    there is no such archive
```

Comment: you're using x, when you should be using a.  You're not extracting from an archive... you're creating one (adding to an archive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct command for what you want to do:

```
7z a beans.7z personal.php
```